# Proper login using RestSharp

Tags: c#, python, python-requests, restsharp

I am currently converting part of code of `instagram-scraper` (https://github.com/rarcega/instagram-scraper) into C# for private purpose. I need to login to the session and I have difficulty while converting this part of code.

This is part of the code in `instagram-scraper` (in python)

```
session = requests.Session()
session.headers = {'user-agent': CHROME_WIN_UA}
session.cookies.set('ig_pr', '1')
session.headers.update({'Referer': BASE_URL})

req = session.get(BASE_URL)
session.headers.update({'X-CSRFToken': req.cookies['csrftoken']})
login_data = {'username': LOGIN_NAME, 'password': LOGIN_PWD}
login = session.post(LOGIN_URL, data = login_data, allow_redirects = True)

session.headers.update({'X-CSRFToken': login.cookies['csrftoken']})
```

And I am using `RestSharp` (https://www.nuget.org/packages/RestSharp/) for the conversion. This is how I converted:

```
var client = new RestClient(BASE_URL);
var request = new RestRequest(BASE_URL, Method.POST);

request.AddHeader("user-agent", CHROME_WIN_UA);

var jar = new CookieContainer();
jar.Add(new Cookie("ig_pr", "1") { Domain = new Uri(BASE_URL).Host });

client.CookieContainer = jar;
request.AddHeader("Referer", BASE_URL);

IRestResponse baseResponse = client.Execute(request);
foreach (var cookie in baseResponse.Cookies) {
    if (cookie.Name == "csrftoken") request.AddHeader("X-CSRFToken", cookie.Value);
}
```

This is the farthest I could convert, and I couldn't convert `login = session.post(LOGIN_URL, data = login_data, allow_redirects = True)`. I have no idea how to convert this code into C# code using `RestSharp`.